# What is Differences in this texts?

Tags: python-3.x

I write a simple code in python but I encountered a very different problem. Python sees the same 2 text differently, and moreover notepad++ & diffchecker.com does this at. How is this possible?

First text:

```
RMX.jeeperscreepers203.rar
```

Second Text:

```
RMX.﻿jeeperscreepers203.rar
```

Do not use CTRL+F because Browser see this text is same. Here is files:

Here is a diffchecker link: https://www.diffchecker.com/WDaUgaoG/

Here is .txt file (2 line): https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5cfb21084fcab97fb0b05d40d07aef9520231222192643/fc021b

Comment: "Python sees the same 2 text differently" What makes you say that?

Comment: Get the lines on txt and run in python.
if "RMX.jeeperscreepers203.rar" == "RMX.jeeperscreepers203.rar":
    print("Same text")
else:
    print("Not same")

Comment: @YunusEmreUlusoy Try `bytes()` on the two strings to see where they're different

Comment: As noted in the answer, there is a byte order mark in the second string. BOM is usually at the start of a file. Was this string built from substrings? Perhaps from data read from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line on your .txt file has the following Unicode code points:

> U+0052 U+004D U+0058 U+002E U+006A U+0065 U+0065 U+0070 U+0065 U+0072 U+0073 U+0063 U+0072 U+0065 U+0065 U+0070 U+0065 U+0072 U+0073 U+0032 U+0030 U+0033 U+002E U+0072 U+0061 U+0072

while the second line has the following code points:

> U+0052 U+004D U+0058 U+002E **U+FEFF** U+006A U+0065 U+0065 U+0070 U+0065 U+0072 U+0073 U+0063 U+0072 U+0065 U+0065 U+0070 U+0065 U+0072 U+0073 U+0032 U+0030 U+0033 U+002E U+0072 U+0061 U+0072

This can be checked on any Unicode-to-code-point viewer, such as [this website](https://onlinetools.com/unicode/convert-unicode-to-code-points).

Diff-ing that would show an additional `U+FEFF` code point on position 5 at the second text, which is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character.

If you want the two texts to be the same, filter only the printable characters:

```py
import string

text1 = "RMX.jeeperscreepers203.rar" 
text2 = "RMX.jeeperscreepers203.rar"

text1 = ''.join(filter(str.isprintable, text1))
text2 = ''.join(filter(str.isprintable, text2))

if text1 == text2:
    print("Same text")
else:
    print("Not same")
```